# Vimscript: how to get current filetype as a variable

Tags: vim

I'd like to get the current filetype as a variable in vimscript.

I'm making a function  that grabs the current filetype and edits another file of corresponding filetype.

For example:

- editing "foo/bar.txt", want to open "tmp/other.txt"
- editing "foo/bar.cpp", want to open "tmp/other.cpp"

etc. I know that `:set ft?` displays the filetype in vim, but I'm not sure how to capture it and then open another file using it as part of the new file string.

Comment: `&filetype` does not necessarily correspond to the filename extension!  Do you really want to use filetype for this, or would you rather parse the `bufname("%")` like `fnamemodify(bufname("%"), ":t")` to extract the current file's extension?   For example, a file named 'foo.hpp' has a `&filetype` of cpp.  Do you want to open "tmp/other.cpp" or "tmp/other.hpp" in this case?

Answer (score 37):

You can access the value of a setting by prefixing it with an ampersand. To assign the filetype to a variable, the following are equivalent:

```
let my_filetype = &filetype
let my_filetype = &ft
```

So for your example, assuming the filetype of the current buffer has been set, you could do something like

```
execute 'edit tmp/other.' . &filetype
```

Note that you need to `execute` the expression so that the variable is expanded before the strings are concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

File type and file suffix are not necessarily the same thing. For example, if you are editing a .txt file, let zft = &ft sets zft to "text". let zfs = fnamemodify(bufname("%"), ":e") sets zfs to "txt".