# Vimscript: &filetype and &syntax are always an empty string

Tags: vim

I feel like what I am trying to do couldn't be easier. I have this file `after/syntax/custom.vim`. It outlines some very simple syntax highlighting rules I want applied to all file types. The highlighting rules work. Hardcoding `f_type` to python or something and forcing the filetype will work great! I am attempting to do the following in my .vimrc:

```
let f_type = &syntax
execute printf("autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * set syntax=%s.custom", f_type)
```

I also tried doing `&filetype` but this and `&syntax` always return an empty string. Any help at all would be lovely.

I followed this [Vimscript: how to get current filetype as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717571/vimscript-how-to-get-current-filetype-as-a-variable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

some reason this is not working...

**Update**:
I figured out a solution that works but it is... silly.

```
command APPLYCUSTOM execute printf("set syntax=%s.custom", &syntax)
autocmd VimEnter * APPLYCUSTOM
```

This seems to work but if I consolidate this to one line it will throw an error (but still work) same thing when trying on the `Syntax` event.

Comment: My question is what you want to accomplish. Because if you want run script globally then why not insert your code into `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 0):

No, your solution isn't silly, it has to do with the timing of the execution. The first one assigns to `f_type` the value of `'syntax'` **as it is during initialization**. When `~/.vimrc` is sourced, **no buffer has yet been loaded**, so there's no filetype nor syntax!

The second one moves the evaluation of `&syntax` to the runtime of the custom `APPLYCUSTOM` command, and that runs on `VimEnter`, which is far later (but still will only apply to the first opened file!)

To avoid the need of the custom command, you need to evaluate during autocmd execution:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * execute 'setlocal syntax=' . &syntax . '.custom'
```

This can be written in a nicer way by using `:let`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * let &l:syntax .= '.custom'
```

#### Alternative

However, I would instead benefit from the built-in `Syntax` event, and directly source the syntax script instead of augmenting the syntax via a compound name. (Plugins may be confused by that, and I also don't think it's helpful to have `custom` included in all syntax names (e.g. when including syntax in the statusline)):

```
autocmd Syntax * runtime after/syntax/custom.vim
```

You only need to ensure that this comes after `:syntax on` in your `~/.vimrc`, so that it gets executed *after* the original syntax script.